# Implementing authorization grant using dotnetopenauth?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm fairly new to authentication implementation but have been trying to implement the above for a while with no success.

From what I understand, authorization grant involves redirecting the user to another website to login and then the browser will redirect back to the origin providing access tokens etc and thats how a user is authenticated.

Is this correct?

I've been using the Dotnetopenauth client library to try and do this with no success.

This is the main method:

```
try
{
   var authState = new AuthorizationState(TestScopes) 
        { Callback = new Uri("http://client/callback") };
   var authRedirectResponse = await 
        _webServerClient.PrepareRequestUserAuthorizationAsync(authState);
   Uri authCompleteUri;
   System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

   using (var response = await client.GetAsync(authRedirectResponse.Headers.Location))
   {
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      authCompleteUri = response.Headers.Location;
   }

   var authCompleteRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, authCompleteUri);
   var result = await _webServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorizationAsync(authCompleteRequest);
}
catch
{
    //refreshTokenSource.TrySetCanceled();
}
```

It always fails on

```
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(authRedirectResponse.Headers.Location))
```

with the error that result is null even though the `headers.location` contains the correct url (which i can browse to and get a login page)

what am i doing wrong?